# Adding values from two table and storing into third table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Amount, ContactName, State, City) 
values 
(
    (Select Amount from Table2 where id=12)+
    (Select Amount from Table3 where id=13),
    'Sam',Newyork,'Newyork'
);
```

I was trying to Store the value of amount in Table1 by the sum of Table2 + Table3 `Amount`

Comment: And what is the Problem with it?

Comment: Any database exception?

Comment: You have missed out on '' around the State variable.

Comment: So what you are getting ? any result or an error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try another way:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Amount, ContactName, State, City) 
values 
(
     select sum(Amount) Amount
       from (Select Amount from Table2 where id=12
             union all
             Select Amount from Table3 where id=13),
    'Sam',Newyork,'Newyork'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `nvl(sum(Amount),0)`. The `SUM` will sum all values in the table  and if there will be no rows you will get `NULL`. The `NVL` will remove possible `NULL` and it will replace it with `0`.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Amount, ContactName, State, City) 
values 
(
    (Select nvl(sum(Amount),0) from Table2 where id=12)+
    (Select nvl(sum(Amount),0) from Table3 where id=13),
    'Sam','Newyork','Newyork'
);
```